# PythonXY: Error when compiling C Extension on Windows: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: python, gcc, windows-7-x64, mingw32, pythonxy

I face a problem when compiling pyxrr (http://carichte.github.io/pyxrr/) on a Windows 7 machine (64bit) when using the latest Version of PythonXY with mingw32.
In the past the Compilation worked without problems on similar machines.

The following error output is given:

```
run setup.py build -c mingw32
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pyxrr.xrr' extension
C:\MinGW32-xy\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\c
ore\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c pyxrr/xrr.c -o build\temp.
win32-2.7\Release\pyxrr\xrr.o -fopenmp
In file included from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/nda
rraytypes.h:1761:0,
                 from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/nda
rrayobject.h:17,
                 from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/arr
ayobject.h:4,
                 from pyxrr/xrr.c:26:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:
12:9: note: #pragma message: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/nu
mpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disa
ble it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
 #pragma message(_WARN___LOC__"Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
         ^
writing build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyxrr\xrr.def
C:\MinGW32-xy\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyxrr\xrr.o bu
ild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyxrr\xrr.def -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuil
d -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-2.7\pyxrr\xrr.pyd -fopenmp
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyxrr\xrr.o:xrr.c:(.text+0x188): undefined referenc
e to `cexp'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyxrr\xrr.o:xrr.c:(.text+0x32c): undefined referenc
e to `cexp'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyxrr\xrr.o:xrr.c:(.text+0x42c): undefined referenc
e to `cexp'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyxrr\xrr.o:xrr.c:(.text+0xb4a): undefined referenc
e to `cexp'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyxrr\xrr.o:xrr.c:(.text+0xccf): undefined referenc
e to `cexp'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyxrr\xrr.o:xrr.c:(.text+0xda5): more undefined ref
erences to `cexp' follow
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyxrr\xrr.o:xrr.c:(.text+0x100e): undefined referen
ce to `csqrt'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyxrr\xrr.o:xrr.c:(.text+0x1898): undefined referen
ce to `csqrt'
c:/mingw32-xy/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build
\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyxrr\xrr.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

The same error occures if I do not use the multi processing option and libraries (--single-core flag). I was searching the web and trying different compiler options like -lm, -DKM_WIN32 etc. without effect. But python as well as mingw run as 32bit versions.

Apparently he doesn't find complex.h library functions which are actually standard.
I tried this on 2 different Win7 machines. Also, compiling using Anaconda works for the single-threaded version.

Since I don't really understand the problems, I hope someone can tell me where it lies.

Any hint is appreciated,
Thank you!

Comment: By the way, it works with older PythonXY Versions and on Linux without any problem.

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve this problem? I am getting a similar error with another library on Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: no, for the moment, I use an older version of pythonXY which compiles it. Sure this is not very satisfying